# Wordpress Custom post type order by meta Query

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

the query does not sort the right way. It should sort it by `meta_value` called `event_date`. (ASC or DESC, both not working)

I have 4 example dates.

```
2019-11-04
2019-10-31
2019-10-29
2019-10-28
```

They are also saved like this.

My query looks like:

```
$events = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => $WP_Capone_Plugin->get_Capone_Events_post_type(),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'         => 'event_date',
            'meta_type'        => 'DATETIME',
            'orderby'          => 'meta_value_datetime',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        ));
```

The result of this query is:

```
2019-11-04
2019-10-28
2019-10-29
2019-10-31
```

Tried a few other ways, but nothing is working the right way.

Comment: in what order do you want it exactly?

Comment: Like this: 2019-11-04
2019-10-31
2019-10-29
2019-10-28

Comment: Try "meta_value" instead of "meta_value_datetime"

Comment: Not working with this change

Answer (score 0):

you should add this

```
'meta_key'=>'event_date',
'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
'order'=>'DESC'
```

Comment: Do you mean that the OP should use "meta_value_num" instead of "meta_value_datetime"? Why is that?